# My iPhone Literally Gets Full When I Connect To Computer

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

0 bytes available even though the apps on my phone aren't close to filling the 16GB. I don't sync with iTunes, all I do is debug apps with Xcode. On iTunes it shows that "other" mostly fills it up. It's iPhone 6 Plus OS 9.2.1.

I have already hit "Erase all content and settings" 3 times, it works until I connect it to my computer and debug an app I'm working on on Xcode - (I delete the app after I use it too).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Back up to computer, encrypt, then restore that backup from computer. From: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ESR9TgauXUI&feature=cards&src_vid=y4kgYqGyu2Y&annotation_id=5ddace4f-cf63-42fc-aab9-9e11916da3c3

Answer (score 0):

Because Autofill is on In your iTunes, 
Simply Connect your phone to iTunes then Go to Summary then Uncheck Autofill.

Comment: Uh...every syncing option is unchecked

Comment: Even all Autofill and all those craps??

Comment: Then only one option left, uninstall iTunes and then again install!

Answer (score 0):

It is filling the others. You probably have some apps installed with data. Try to disable/limit sync for apps like Google Drive, Dropbox or even fitness apps where you have to download training videos, etc.